# yyyy-MM-dd date format not working

Tags: vb.net

I can't get my date to format as yyyy-MM-dd, for instance 2013-01/15. I have tried both custom and predefined Date/Time formats.  Any of these should work:

```
    Dim myDate As Date = "01/15/2013"

    myDate = myDate.ToString("o")

    myDate = myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    Format(myDate, "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

But they all keep myDate as "01/15/2013". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Dim myDate As Date = #01/15/2013#` - correct syntax. Use `Option Strict On`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Date` value doesn't have any format at all. When you format the date into a string and assign it back to the variable, it's parsed to a `Date` value again, and loses the formatting.

To keep the date in the formatted string form, you need to keep it as a string:

```
Dim formatted As String = myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: I can accept as answer in 5 minutes, but that did the trick. thanks! It's kinda obnoxious though as I'm passing the variable around as date. As a newbie I guess this is something I'll get used to.  Thanks again.